Any way to cancel C-q quoted-insert?
Is there a way to cancel the quoted-insert that begins when I press C-q? Sometimes when I mean to press C-w, I miss and hit the Q key instead of the W key.
Trying to cancel C-q with C-g inserts a literal ^G character, and pressing escape inserts the ^[ escape character, neither of which is what I want.
Is the only way to get out of C-q to give it something to insert? I can type something innocuous like space or a letter and subsequently delete it or just hit undo, but that has the unfortunate side effect, when in graphical mode, of making the point/mark visualization disappear--annoying if C-w for kill-region is what I was trying to do. (annoying, but not too disruptive: the mark and point are still where they had been, just the highlight for visualizing them disappears)
Is there a way to cancel C-q cleanly, or do I just need to get used to exiting it by typing a printing character? (or better yet, training myself not to accidentally hit C-q when I meant to hit C-w)

If there were a character you could type to cancel C-q, how would you literally insert that character if/when you really wanted it?

A conundrum indeed, @SteveSummit ! I could imagine something like C-q C-q going into a special "confirm quoted-insert mode" where a third C-q means "I mean it, give me ^Q" and C-g means "cancel this quoted-insert" but that would be overly complex :) I think the answer from Gilles about putting a partial octal entry in and then hitting C-g is the best course.

Type a digit, then quit. E.g. C-q 0 C-g. When you type a digit, it's the beginning of an octal code (or decimal or hexadecimal depending on your configuration). Once read-quoted-char (the function that powers C-q) goes into the mode where it reads digits, quitting works.

Perfect! It even preserves the point/mark visualization


Is the only way to get out of C-q to give it something to insert?

Yes, most of the time, since by the time you realize you've accidentally hit C-q instead of C-w, you've also already typed another char. At least that's the case for me.

I can type something innocuous like space or a letter and subsequently delete it or just hit undo,

Yes. But I think most of the time most people will have already typed another char after C-q, before they realize their mistake. Just delete it or undo.

but that has the unfortunate side effect, when in graphical mode, of making the point/mark visualization disappear

Just use C-x C-x (command exchange-point-and-mark).  Use it twice, if you want to put point and mark back where they were.
Note too that if someone uses delete-selection-mode then there's no problem at all, because hitting C-q immediately deletes the active region (because C-q inserts a character).

Update after seeing this downvoted and @Gilles' type-0-then-C-g answer accepted.
If you accidentally hit C-q instead of C-w and you've already continued typing other keys, then you don't discover you've hit C-q till you've already hit a key that responds to the C-q prompt. In that case, it's too late to hit 0 and then C-g.
At least in my usage, this is the (far) more common occurrence when I accidentally hit C-q.

Thanks for the reminder that C-x C-x swaps point and mark, thereby refreshing the visualization. For my C-w purposes, the ordering does not matter much, but in cases where it does, the repeatability is quite nice!

Someone want to explain the downvote?

Cannot speak for the downvoter, but I upvoted your answer even though I found the one from Gilles more pertinent to my situation. I agree with your update, too! So far I have mostly noticed as soon as I see the C-q prompt in the minibuffer, so bailing out with partial octal works great for that, but in a fast-typing scenario where you entered something you did not want literalized, C-_ followed by C-x C-x seems like the ideal solution.
